# Celery: making a copy of a task

Tags: python, celery

If I have a task already scheduled with Celery - is it possible to make a copy of that task, and change the ETA?  Rationale is that I want to essentially preview what will happen at the actual scheduled time.  Scheduling two tasks with different ETAs at the outset is not an option as the 'preview' will be on-demand.

Thanks for any help/advice!